# 3D : keep horizon drawn on screen at the same height regardless camera's zoom

Tags: math, 3d, camera, projection-matrix

I have this strange use case.

These variables are known:

- Camera zoom (or fov)
- Camera rotation (orientation) around Y and Z axis `= 0`

Now, I want the ***horizon*** (horizon position `= (0,0,Infinite)`) to be drawn on screen at a ***specific*** 2D height "YY". What must be the Camera X-axis rotation so that the horizon is drawn at "YY"?

You might ask why may I need this: well, when I change the camera zoom, the horizon changes position on screen (in all cases except when X-axis rotation `= 0`). I need to be able to change the camera zoom AND keep the horizon unchanged (relatively to its 2D position). AFAIK, this can only be achieved by changing the X-axis rotation accordingly.

Comment: ground is plane,sphere,ellipsoid or mesh ?

Comment: It's irrelevant. Horizon is an infinite horizontal line infinitely far away

Comment: that is true only if your Zfar is big enough and you do not want to see what is on the ground actually ... if you add rotation around z then it is not horizontal at all ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a well-defined symmetric view frustum, the solution can be found with some simple geometry:

[image: Problem Visualization]

I assume `YY` is in normalized device coordinates (ranging from -1 to 1). If they are in pixel coordinates, you have to convert them.

I have chosen the projection plane to be 1 unit far away from the camera. But any other distance would work as well. Then, the distance `y'` is simply

```
y' = YY * H/2
```

`H/2` is the half screen height and can be calculated with:

```
H/2 = tan (fovy/2)
```

where `fovy` is the camera's field of view in the vertical direction.

You want to find angle `alpha` for your rotation. This is simply:

```
tan alpha = y' / 1 = YY * tan(fovy / 2)
    alpha = atan(YY * tan(fovy / 2)
```

Be aware of the direction. Positive values specify downward rotations.

---

For arbitrary projections, this problem can be solved analytically:

Assuming we have projection matrix `P` and view matrix `V`, we want to solve for:

```
w-clip(P * V * (0 0 1 0)^T) = (... YY ...)
```

Since you only want to allow translations and rotations about the x-axis for your camera, `V` has the form:

```
    / 1  0           0          tx \
V = | 0  cos alpha  -sin alpha  ty |
    | 0  sin alpha   cos alpha  tz |
    \ 0  0           0          1  /
```

This yields the equation:

```
YY = (p23 * cos alpha - p22 * sin alpha) / (p43 * cos alpha - p42 * sin alpha)
```

where `pij` is the entry of `P` in the `i`-th row and `j`-th column.

Use your favorite symbolic solver to get a solution for `alpha` and you can re-calculate your view-matrix.